# How to render different component with react router after user logged in

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following router class:

```
function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/SignUp" exact component={SignUp} />
          <Route path="/ForgotPassword" exact component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Route path="/ChangePassword" exact component={ChangePassword} />

          <Authenticated>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/startTest" exact component={StartTest} />
            </Switch>
          </Authenticated>

          <Authenticated>
            <Header />
            <Shell>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/TestResult" exact component={TestResult} />
                <Route path="/TestList" exact component={TestList} />
                <Route path="/Home" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route component={GenericNotFound} />
              </Switch>
            </Shell>
            <Footer />
          </Authenticated>

          <Route component={GenericNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**Authenticate.js**

```
function Authenticated({ children }) {
  const history = useHistory();
  if (!IsLoggedIn()) {
    history.push(`/login`);
  }

  if (IsLoggedIn()) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  } else {
    return <></>;
  }
}
```

As you can see there are two `Authenticated` tag I have used.

Based on the page, for example if the path is `"/startTest"` and user logged in, I don't want to load Header/Footer.

But in other cases like if user at `"Home"` page, I want to load `Header/Footer` component.

When I try to browse `Home/TestResult/TestList` pages, it loads nothing. If I remove one `Authenticated` component tag from HTML, it works fine.

Comment: Can you share your code for the Authenticated component?

Comment: Can you try console logging  IsloggedIn()?

Comment: @BimalDas Given that you are on `/startTest` route and you are logged in. And you do not want to render Header/Footer But it will render header and Footer component as IsLoggedIn will return true for both Authenticated components

Comment: @BimalDas I think you can able to render header and footer inside that component I think it will help but I'm not sure it this right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only return one component per route and handle authentication within the routed component. Here an example, which handles your Header/Footer case.

```
function Authenticated ({component: Component, hasFooterHeader, ...rest}) {
  const authed = IsLoggedIn();
  let page = <>;
  if (hasFooterHeader) {
    page = (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Shell>
          <Component {...rest} />
        </Shell>
        <Footer />
      <>
    );
  } else {
    page = <Component {...rest} />;
  }
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authed === true
        ? page
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
    />
  )
}
```

And the Routing would look like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
  <Route path="/SignUp" exact component={SignUp} />
  <Route path="/ForgotPassword" exact component={ForgotPassword} />
  <Route path="/ChangePassword" exact component={ChangePassword} />
  <Authenticated path="/startTest" exact component={StartTest} />
  <Authenticated path="/TestResult" exact component={TestResult} hasFooterHeader />
  <Authenticated path="/TestList" exact component={TestList} hasFooterHeader />
  <Authenticated path="/Home" exact component={Home} hasFooterHeader />
  <Authenticated path="/" exact component={Home} hasFooterHeader />
  <Authenticated component={GenericNotFound} hasFooterHeader />
  <Route component={GenericNotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
this.props.match.params if I browse any page which is having router parameters

Comment: You should just be able to pass down the props from the component. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yea working. :) Some reason, I needed to change the code to this.props.computedMatch.params.

Answer (score 0):

When you use react route in app 
it's important to build clear and extendable code framework

I suggest you seal the Authenticated and Layout under route component

like `baselayout.js` in `base` 
then `accountlayout`, `pagelayout` extend `base`
then read array of router like `[ name :home, layout: pagelayout, auth: authed ]` 
dynamic load router use js

it's not suitable we `Auth` under `BrowserRouter` with `Switch`

you can check umi.js [enter link description here](https://github.com/umijs/umi)